# Pressure Transducer to complete circuit

Tags: circuit-design, transducer, pressure

I'm using the Adafruit Feather nRF52 to build the HIDScan sketch which essentially allows completed circuits to transmit keys over bluetooth.  I have a switch that connects from pin A0 to GND, and when I trigger the physical switch, it sends a signal.

I want to swap out the circuit to use a pressure switch for a Sip & Puff 'trigger' which would complete the circuit when I either blow or suck on a connecting tube.  I don't have this trigger, but think maybe I need a Pressure transducer, and  I'm looking at something like http://www.ebay.ca/itm/0-40kPa-Atmospheric-Pressure-Transducer-Sensor-Module-3-3V-Power-Supply-/401405291040?hash=item5d759eaa20:g:15cAAOSwcUBYSNSp but I have no idea how to hook this up, or if it will do the job.

I think I understand that the transducer will give a variable voltage, but what I really want is just to detect any voltage (eg. puff or no puff) and complete the circuit.  I don't care about intensity.

Am I missing something, or is the wrong piece for the job?  Do I need some kind of relay?

I don't have a lot of experience understanding data sheets, and am fairly new to circuits in general.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't say about the pressure sensor, but if its an analog voltage output, following that with an open-collector comparator like a lm311 will allow you to replace the switch

Comment: @sstobbe Thanks, If I read the spec right, LM311 needs 5v, however I have a 3.3v onboard chip, so I think I need to use an LM6511.  Is there another equivalent better chip or recommendation?

Comment: Yes, if you are limited to using a 3V3 supply something like the comparator you mention would work. Just watch out for the input voltage range, for the LM6511, the max input is Vcc-1.5V, min is 0.5 V. I'm also not sure if the pressure sensor you selected is absolute or gauge. If it only responds to positive guage pressure the 'suck' will output the same as ambient.